# Show QQuickWidget inside QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qml, qgraphicsscene, qquickwidget

I was upgrading some old code that was working fine to display my qml files inside a QGraphicsScene, but I was using the QDeclarativeView + QGraphicsProxyWidget method, so I converted to the new QT 6.5 / qtquick 2 format using QQuickWidget.

OLD CODE (QT 4.8 / qt quick 1) - Working fine

```
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QML_view = new QDeclarativeView;
    QDeclarativeContext *context = QML_view->rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty( "Vars_list", QVariant::fromValue( dataList ) );
    QML_view->rootContext()->setContextProperty( "myObject", this );
    QML_view->setSource( QUrl( "myqmlfile.qml" ) );

    QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = scene.addWidget( QML_view );
    proxy->setZValue( 10 );
```

NEW CODE (QT 6.5 / qt quick 1)

```
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QQuickWidget *QML_widget = new QQuickWidget();
    QQmlContext* context = QML_widget->rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty( "Vars_list", QVariant::fromValue( dataList ) );
    QML_widget->rootContext()->setContextProperty( "myObject", this );
    QML_widget->setSource( QUrl( "myqmlfile.qml" ) );

    scene.addWidget( QML_widget );
```

The qml shows up ok but all the qml buttons are unresponsive, and any existing buttons I may have on my QGraphicsScene show up on top of the qml display too.

So I tried another way replacing scene.addWidget( QML_widget ) with QML_widget->show().
The qml file now works as supposed, but as I was expecting I now have a second separate window opened on the taskbar which I don't want. Any clues about what's the best approach here to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Qt 6.5.0 and QtQuick.Controls 6.5 everything works fine. As per this [page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols1-index.html) it says QtQuick.Controls 1 is deprecated.

> Warning: The Qt Quick Controls 1 module is deprecated since Qt 5.12.
> Use the latest Qt Quick Controls module instead.

The buttons in my Main.qml are responsive and output the desired  console message. Also the QML widget is on top of the `QPushButton` if I use the line `proxy->setZValue(10);` same as you did in your Qt 4.8 example code.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/untitled15/Main.qml"_qs);

    QGraphicsScene scene;

    QQuickWidget *quickWidget = new QQuickWidget();
    quickWidget->setSource(url);

    QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = scene.addWidget(quickWidget);
    proxy->setZValue(10);

    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Button");
    scene.addWidget(button);

    QGraphicsView view(&scene);
    view.setWindowTitle("Hello World");
    view.resize(800, 600);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 300

    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Text {
            text: "Hello from QML"
            color: "red"
        }

        Button {
            text: "Button #0"
            onPressed: console.log("pressed", text)
        }
        Button {
            text: "Button #1"
            onPressed: console.log("pressed", text)
        }
        Button {
            text: "Button #2"
            onPressed: console.log("pressed", text)
        }
    }
}
```